# Opsworks Rails Console Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-opsworks

I am trying to run a rails console in amazon opsworks, I have tried:

```
sudo rails console -e production
sudo rails console production
RAILS_ENV=production sudo rails console
RAILS_ENV=production RACK_ENV=production sudo rails console
```

With each of those commands the console is spinning up in the development environment. What do I need to do to get this console started in the environment of my choosing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are ssh'd into the instance.

`$ cd /srv/www/yourapplication/current`

`$ sudo bundle exec rails console`

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo su deploy  # switch to the app user
cd /srv/www/myapp/current  # your deploy dir might be different (check logs if unsure)
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get an error about the environment variables being missing.

Comment: @MattGibson sorry I haven't used the environment variable support. The cookbooks just [write them into the unicorn.conf file](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/fb21127bf1e79e91ccbeaa47907774898bc237c5/unicorn/templates/default/unicorn.conf.erb#L16) so I'm not sure there's an elegant way to reuse them from there.

Comment: @MattGibson See my answer, which adds `-E` to the sudo command.  That should load the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 (faster):
You can add environment variables from .env(.environment)-file with this gem https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv. You have to write down all keys and values in this file which you need to load.

Solution 2 (better):
Do it like described here: http://dev.mikamai.com/post/90567083464/use-the-env-luke-aka-simulate-the-env-in

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer to load environment variables without running it as root and without adding dotenv to your Gemfile:

```
$ cd /srv/www/<NAME_OF_YOUR_APP>/current
$ sudo -u deploy -E bundle exec rails console production
```